# Deploy Docker stack with Nginx and Gunicorn on a server with Apache

Tags: docker, apache, nginx, docker-compose, gunicorn

I am new to the topic of Docker and servers, little by little I am learning but I have come across a problem about which I do not see much information and in the end I resort to asking.

I have a server on which there is an Apache and I have several webs deployed (in PHP and R). I have created an application in Django, and I have dockerized it using Gunicorn and Nginx, and I am having problems to deploy said app on the server, but since I am a newbie, I don't even know if it is possible to have a Docker stack with Nginx and Gunicorn in a server that has an Apache mounted...

This is the Dockerfile of the Django project:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY project /app

COPY entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

This is the entrypoint:

```
#!/bin/sh

python manage.py migrate --no-input
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input

gunicorn project.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

This is the Nginx Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.19.0-alpine

COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

This is the default.conf file:

```
upstream django {
    server django_gunicorn:8000;
}

server {
    listen 8080;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;
    }
}
```

And this is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  django_gunicorn:
    volumes:
      - static:/static
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  nginx:
    build: nginx
    volumes:
      - static:/static
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - django_gunicorn

volumes:
  static:
```

What docker ps throws:
[image]

If I raise the stack on a server that does not have an Apache, it works, the problem comes when I try to do it on the server that has Apache ... But I don't understand the problem...

I do not know if more information may be needed, if so, I am sorry, you can tell me and I will add it quickly.

Thanks.

Comment: Without testing out your config, I have a question: You have Apache (probably listening to port 80 and maybe 443) on the Host. And on that same host you have a Docker Container running Nginx listening to port 8080 (on the host). That should work. When you start everything, and on the Host you go to http://localhost:8080/, what do you see as a response? What is the actual error?

Comment: A not found
The requested resource was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation learning Dockerizing Django by following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJAfq6Ku4cI) tutorial and faced the same issue.

Modifying the Dockerfile of the Django project:

```
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /
```

to `COPY ./entrypoint.sh .`

worked for me. Hope it helps you too.